# DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.NextBookmark")

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-macros

using VS2010

**ANSWER** thanks to Hans (since I'm to lowly to answer my own question for 8 hrs)

```
 Sub CreateBreakPoint()

        Dim doc As TextDocument = _
                CType(DTE.ActiveDocument.Object("TextDocument"), TextDocument)
        Dim point As EditPoint = doc.StartPoint.CreateEditPoint

        While point.NextBookmark()
            Try
                point.ClearBookmark()
                DTE.Debugger.Breakpoints.Add("", DTE.ActiveDocument.FullName, point.Line(), 1, "", dbgBreakpointConditionType.dbgBreakpointConditionTypeWhenTrue, "c#", "", 0, "", 0, dbgHitCountType.dbgHitCountTypeNone)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("error: " + ex.Message)
            End Try
        End While
        MsgBox("Done")

    End Sub
```

I have a macro that will set breakpoints at every bookmark.  It works (like a sledgehammer)... but out of curiosity how do I do one of the following so that I can use a "proper" For Loop

1. retrieve a list of Bookmark objects (ostensibly with a line number property)
2. check for DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.NextBookmark") to return false or some indication that I've reached the last bookmark
3. retrieve a list of Bookmark objects with a specific "query" so i don't have to first delete all current bookmarks

the current code

```
Public Module BookMarksToBreakPoints


    Sub TemporaryMacro()
        Dim bookmarkWin As Window = DTE.Windows.Item(WindowKinds.vsWindowKindBookmarks)

        While True
            Try
                DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.NextBookmark")
                DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleBookmark")
                DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.ToggleBreakpoint")
            Catch e As Exception
                MsgBox("Done")
                Exit While
            End Try
        End While

    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Use EditPoint2.NextBookmark().  It returns a bool.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Hans Passant for the push in the right direction.  The final macro:

```
Sub CreateBreakPoint()

    Dim doc As TextDocument = _
            CType(DTE.ActiveDocument.Object("TextDocument"), TextDocument)
    Dim point As EditPoint = doc.StartPoint.CreateEditPoint

    While point.NextBookmark()
        Try
            point.ClearBookmark()
            DTE.Debugger.Breakpoints.Add("", DTE.ActiveDocument.FullName, point.Line(), 1, "", dbgBreakpointConditionType.dbgBreakpointConditionTypeWhenTrue, "c#", "", 0, "", 0, dbgHitCountType.dbgHitCountTypeNone)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("error: " + ex.Message)
        End Try
    End While
    MsgBox("Done")

End Sub
```