# Accessing Visual studio from an external application

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I was wondering if it is possible to access Visual studio from an external application so that the application reacts to events that occur in visual studio. Either by adding a pre-built extension that is added to visual studio and then interacts with the application and visa versa.

Sort of like an extension that is build as an application first.

What I would like to achieve is to build an application that talks to visual studio. So I would build an application as i would normally do but I would like it to then interact with activity and actions based on what would be happening in visual studio as one uses visual studio.

So if I click on add new project my application, if open, could change text based on that action of clicking on "New project" to "You just click to open a new project" which would be represented in my application.

I think i might just create an extension but i was just wondering if it could also be possible to have another open application that could do this.

Comment: Please describe more en detail what you are trying to achieve. Like this the question will be closed as it is to unspecific.

Comment: I updated it. Hope its a bit better in its description of what i would like to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start by saying that I think an extension might best suit your needs.
But since your question was if it is possible to be done from another application, the answer is **yes**, using the **[Development Tools Environment (DTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.dte.aspx)**. This library allows you to access many Visual Studio features such as:

- [Attaching to another instance of Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cefss65.aspx)
- [Executing commands in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7740199/1379664)

And even [Subscribing to events that happen inside Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7825489/1379664)

DTE can also be used to create macros, add more controls to your VS toolbox etc.